# SQL Query find results with multiple values

Tags: sql

I have a list of contracts like this query:

```
select 
    r.vnum, r.BEITRAGSGR 
from 
    ufrisk r 
inner join 
    ufvert v on r.vnum = v.vnum 
inner join 
    allgvert a on a.vnum = r.vnum 
where 
    a.version = r.version
```

How can I search for all contracts that have more than one (different) value in the column `r.BEITRAGSGR`?

[image: Example Query result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `vnum` is a "contract", you can use aggregation:

```
select vnum
from ufrisk
group by vnum
having min(BEITRAGSGR) <> max(BEITRAGSGR);
```

If you want the original rows, use `exists`:

```
select u.*
from ufrisk u
where exists (select 1
              from ufrisk u2
              where u2.vnum = u.vnum and u2.BEITRAGSGR <> u.BEITRAGSGR
             );
```